# One direction SpotLight with PointerLockControls in Threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, lighting

I'm trying to attach a directional flashlight to the camera (controls object) so the beam is always where center of the screen is aiming at.
This is my code:

```
controls = new PointerLockControls( camera, document.body );
var flashlight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 7, 50, 0.8*Math.PI);
controls.getObject().add(flashlight);
controls.getObject().add(flashlight.target);
```

but the result is the light around camera, not a straight beam. (see pic below)

[image: Flashlight beam]

so how can I achieve a **directional beam**?

//edit, added Group.

```
controls = new PointerLockControls( camera, document.body );
var flashlight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 7, 50, 0.8*Math.PI);
// camera.add(flashlight);
// camera.add(flashlight.target);
const group = new THREE.Group();
group.add(camera);
group.add(flashlight);  
scene.add(group);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`THREE.Group` to group objects together](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Group)

```js
const group = new THREE.Group();
group.add(camera);
group.add(flashlight);

// Finally, we add the group to our controls
controls = new PointerLockControls( group, document.body );
```

Then you can add the group to your scene, and control the group as a whole. The camera and flashlight will rotate and translate together.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I grouped them as you said but now the light just stays in one place - looks like its not attached anymore to the camera. Why is that?

Comment: You can edit your question with the updated code so I can see what you're doing.

Comment: Right away. I added the code with grouping.

Comment: Ah, yes. You forgot now that you've created the `group`, you have to add the group to your Controls, instead of just `camera`. If you only add the camera then we're back to square one. I've updated my answer with that step too.

Comment: Ah so simple! It did fix the problem with light not moving, but we are again at the beggining, light is not acting like a spotLight, it's more of a pointLight for some reason.